# How do I pull Laravel projects from Github that don't include the framework files?

Tags: git, laravel, github, frameworks

Trying to pull a GitHub project.

Project on GitHub does not include Laravel backbone files, 'vendor, artisan, etc...'

So I create a Laravel project on my local computer and pull in the files from GitHub. However this is not working.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is in `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have cloned your GitHub repo, try and:

- use a tool like [`jadjoubran/laravel-ng-artisan-generators`](https://github.com/jadjoubran/laravel-ng-artisan-generators) or [`Jeroen-G/laravel-packager`](https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager) in order to generate a template project with the missing elements (vendor/artisan) and
- see if you can merge the cloned sources in it.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
$ composer install
```

in the project directory.

If you don't have composer [install it](https://getcomposer.org/download/)